# Please let ♦'s comment on deleted questions/answers

Tags: feature-request, comments, deleted-questions, moderator-tools, deleted-answers

When challenged, users sometimes delete their question/answer and run away from it (but not the site). Sometimes ♦'s want to comment in order to explain the situation. There is no better education/general messaging system for users than commenting, and I hate, completely always absolutely hate, undeleting an answer, even for a moment, in order to comment and re-delete the answer. Not to mention doing this clears the "deleted by owner" status which can lead to further confusion;

> "Jason? Why did you delete this answer? It's low quality but not wrong."
>
> "I didn't, I had to undelete it to leave those comments, then re-delete it to respect the owner's original action/decision."
>
> "Oh"

Education and messaging is important. Please don't encumber it for those who get things done.

Comment: Aren't Diamonds able to send messages to users?

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby Individual users, sure. However, 1) moderator messages are typically reserved for infractions, warnings, and similarly negative type things. 2) They are only sent to one user at a time whereas comments are signposts available for others as well.

Comment: @SulfurizedDemonbobby yes, but they're almost exclusively reserved for "Oh god stop that *right now* or you're banned" messages. They'd be major overkill for "hey, this isn't an answer"

Comment: @Ahrotahntee Jason isn't saying that all self deletes are wrong, merely that there are times where the answer could have been fixed instead of just deleted, or even that it was fine as it stood and didn't need to be deleted at all.  In other cases it's not that the deletion was wrong, but that there is an opportunity to explain to the user what, specifically, was wrong with the answer and why it was received negatively by the community.  Occasionally I see people delete an answer the second it has a negative score, even if they don't know what was wrong with it.

Comment: In my defense, the similar question finder did not find this question even with tags. In my prosecution, I didn't bother searching even though I'm not surprised this issue isn't original. In BoltClock's defense, good job.